# Django 1.10 - subdomain is not workig with django_hosts

Tags: python, django, subdomain

I am following this tutorial on youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdZsQEL2WXk&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzQSEMN5PXvEWuD2gEWVngCZ&index=23) about implement subdomain with django_host, I think I did everything right but still not working when I type the Url: **blog.tirr.com:8000** and an error is raised:

**"Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'blog.tirr.com:8000'. You may need to add 'blog.tirr.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS."**

### settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['tirr.com', 'www.tirr.com'] (in the youtube video shows adding only these 2)

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_hosts',
    'shortener',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'kirr.urls'
ROOT_HOSTCONF = 'kirr.hosts'
DEFAULT_HOST = 'www'
DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL = "http://www.tirr.com:8000"
```

### hosts.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django_hosts import patterns, host

host_patterns = patterns('',
    host(r'www', settings.ROOT_URLCONF, name='www'),
    host(r'(?!www).*', 'kirr.hostsconf.urls', name='wildcard'),
)
```

### hostsconf/

### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import wildcard_redirect

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<path>.*)', wildcard_redirect),
]
```

### views.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL = getattr(settings, "DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL",     "http://www.tirr.com:8000")

def wildcard_redirect(request, path=None):
    new_url = DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL
    if path is not None:
        new_url = DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL + "/" + path
return HttpResponseRedirect(new_url)
```

Comment: try changing the: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['tirr.com', 'www.tirr.com', 'blog.tirr.com']`

Comment: if you see the django tutorial, you could see that " blog.tirr.com " is not in ALLOWED_HOSTS. The problem is another.

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly says what to do. In `settings.py` change

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['blog.tirr.com', 'tirr.com']`

Comment: if you see the django tutorial, you could see that " blog.tirr.com " is not in ALLOWED_HOSTS. The problem is another.

Answer (score 0):

You miss a dot before tirr.com

```
['.tirr.com', 'www.tirr.com']
```

That will cater for the subdomains